# Where to store the docker-php-ext files?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I have set up a Symfony4 project with in a Docker container.

I followed the [Jobeet-Tutorial](https://jobeet-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/days/day-1/) where they use [the phpdocker.io - generator](https://phpdocker.io/generator).

All works perfect but very slow. So I want to speed up and enable the opcache and configure it.

I found helpful links in the net. So I added to my Dockerfile this:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure opcache --enable-opcache \
&& docker-php-ext-install opcache
# Copy configuration
COPY config/opcache.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
```

The problem is that I don't have this helperscripts:

- docker-php-ext-configure
- docker-php-ext-install
- docker-php-ext-enable

So I decided to search it in the internet and copy it into my project.

Now I have it in the php-fpm folder of my docker directory.

My directory looks like this now - the scripts are in the beneath the Dockerfile:

[image]

Is there any other step I forgot to do, like registering these scripts somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most immediate answer to your question is that you need to copy those scripts into the Docker image you are building. To do that, you should create a subdirectory within the `php-fpm` directory named `bin` and put all of those scripts in that directory. Then, in your Dockerfile:

```
COPY bin /usr/local/bin
```

Now when you try to use that image, the scripts will be within your executable `PATH`.

## However

Those `docker-php-ext-*` scripts you found are from [the PHP project's official Docker images](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/ecd7dcc69c) and are intended to be used with those images.

You are using the `phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest` image, [which seems to use `ubuntu:bionic` as a base image](https://github.com/phpdocker-io/base-images/blob/master/php/7.3/cli/Dockerfile#L5). These scripts depend heavily on the PHP Dockerfiles, which do a bunch of preparatory steps, such as [downloading the source code for the PHP interpreter itself to `/usr/src`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ecd7dcc69c/7.3/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile#L59-L80). Making these scripts run directly in a `phpdockerio` container would be a very involved process.

That leaves you with 2 options:

1. Forgo the scripts and install Ubuntu's prebuilt packages. You [seem to already have](https://github.com/phpdocker-io/base-images/blob/master/php/7.3/cli/Dockerfile#L21-L30) the apcu, apcu-bc, cli, curl, json, mbstring, opcache, readline, xml, and zip PHP extensions installed. You can see the full list of packages that are available from the default repos this way by running

   ```sh
   docker run --rm -it phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest bash -c 'apt-get update && apt search ^php7.3-';
   ```

   When you know which packages you want, you can add them to your Dockerfile.

2. Switch to using an official PHP image instead so you can use the `docker-php-ext-*` scripts. The `phpdocker-io` image you are using is essentially PHP7.3-FPM on Ubuntu, and the closest official PHP image to that is `php:7.3-fpm-stretch` (Debian 9). You can build and install the extensions listed in Option 1 by changing your PHP-FPM Dockerfile to:

   ```
   FROM php:7.3-fpm-stretch

   # Run in Bash instead of Bourne shell to get lists
   RUN ["bash", "-c", " \
       #Exits on error or unbound variable. Now we can use semicolons instead of
       #ampersands
       set -eu; \
   \
       ext_build_dependencies=( \
           #Needed to build php-curl
           libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
           \
           #Needed to build php-mbstring
           libedit-dev \
           \
           #Needed to build php-xml \
           libxml2-dev \
           \
           #Needed to build php-zip
           zlib1g-dev libzip-dev \
       ); \
   \
       apt-get update; \
       apt-get install -y ${ext_build_dependencies[@]}; \
   \
       #Build the extensions
       docker-php-ext-install curl json mbstring readline xml zip ; \
       pecl install apcu apcu_bc; \
   \
       apt-get purge -y ${ext_build_dependencies[@]}; \
       apt-get autoremove -y; \
       apt-get clean -y; \
   "]
   ```

If Ubuntu 18 and Debian were binary-compatible ([they're not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41407#answer-41426)), you could try a third option, which would be building the extensions using a PHP image, then copying over the built extensions [as the second stage of a multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build#use-multi-stage-builds). This would be possible if your image uses the same Linux flavor as as the PHP image does. For example, if your image were based on `alpine:3.8`, you could use `php:7.3-fpm-alpine3.8` to build your extensions and copy them over.

Comment: Wow. I applichiate your detailed answer. Thats great. I will try to get the second way working. Hope it will not be very hard for me. I am new to all this linux - server stuff.